# Как появилось слово "здОрово" в значениях очень сильно, а также великолепно, ловко, удачно, искусно?

Tags: орфоэпия

Лексические значения ***здОрово*** так далеко ушли от темы здоровья, что невольно возникают сомнения, однокоренные ли они...

Как перекочевало ударение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лексические значения часто расходятся и превращаются в омонимы. Некоторые учёные (Ожегов, например)считают и прилагательные здоровый-имеющий здоровье и здоровый - большой и крепкий омонимами,а от них уже образовались другие части речи - сущ.,наречие,междометие(приветствие), категория состояния.

А исторически оба значения - от слова "дерево".Фасмер говорит, что "праслав. *sъdorvъ, где sъ = др.-инд. su «хороший» (Бодуэн де Куртенэ, Stud. Brückn. 221 и сл.) и *dorvo-, связанного чередованием с де́рево, т. е. «из хорошего дерева»"

Т.е. др.-русск. сторовъ «здоровый» -имеющий здоровье, как могучее дерево, а если углубиться в праславянский - "из хорошего дерева", а это и крепкий, и хороший.Так что однокоренные, как ни глянь.

А ударение часто переходит, чтобы отличить разные морфологические категории - краткое прилагательное- оно здорОво и наречие (кат. сост.) здОрово.